# Formato de horas PHP MYSQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

tengo una pregunta... estoy buscando la manera de guardar los datos de un formulario en php a la base de datos MYSQL.
Al usar la función para cambiar el formato de horas de "2020-01-09 20:43:02" a "3 weeks ago".

```php
function time_elapsed_string($datetime, $full = false) {
    $now = new DateTime;
    $ago = new DateTime($datetime);
    $diff = $now->diff($ago);
    $diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
    $diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;
    $string = array('y' => 'year', 'm' => 'month', 'w' => 'week', 'd' => 'day', 'h' => 'hour', 'i' => 'minute', 's' => 'second');
    foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
        if ($diff->$k) {
            $v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? 's' : '');
        } else {
            unset($string[$k]);
        }
    }
    if (!$full) $string = array_slice($string, 0, 1);
    return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ' ago' : 'just now';
}
```

La base de datos está configurada de esta manera:

```SQL
 CREATE TABLE `AWESOME` (
  `review_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_comment` text NOT NULL,
  `datetime` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Y así es como llamo desde php para enviarlo a la base de datos:

```php
if(isset($_POST["send"]))
{

      $data = array(
        ':user_name'        =>  $_POST["user_name"],            
        ':user_comment'     =>  $_POST["user_comment"],
        ':datetime'         =>  time()
    );

    $query = "
    INSERT INTO database
    (user_name, user_comment, datetime) 
    VALUES (:user_name, :user_comment, :datetime)
    ";

    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

    $statement->execute($data);

    echo "Your comment has been Successfully Submitted";

}
```

Si alguien me puede decir en que estoy fallando se lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: No puedes guardar una fecha en formato 'tree weeks' o '3 weeks' si el campo esta definido como `date` o como `datetime`.

Comment: Lo que busco es guardarlo en la base de datos algo como 2020-01-09 20:43:02 que al leerse se imprima hace 2 años

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo con `date_dif`, te dejo aqui un pequeño ejemplo de como lo podrias hacer. La fecha pasada a la función tiene el siguiente formato `AAAA-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`

```php
    public function diff($date) {
        $today = now();
        $diff = date_diff($date, now());
        return $diff->format('%y Año %m Meses %d Dia');
    }
```

Te recomiendo ver la documentacion oficial de PHP. [Funcion date_dif](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date-diff.php)